# Core dumps in visual studio 2010 from Release build

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, devexpress, coredump

I have build application using .NET 4.0, WinForms and DevExpress Winforms components.
I have a bug that I cannot reproduce using simple "step by step" method.

I am trying to use core dumps to debug this issue.
I can get core dump and view exception nicely inside visual studio using

> adplus -crash -pn Main.exe -o  c:\output -y C:\pdb -fullonfirst

However, this seems to be working only with debug build, with release build I am getting message "No source available, No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed"

How can I get useful information using release build?
Are there any best practices I should use with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to the Release build, Project + Properties, Build tab, scroll down, Advanced.  Change the "Debug Info" setting to Full.  Be sure to change the /y argument, these .pdbs need to be stored separate from the debug versions.

Comment: It worked! Although I'm not getting source code in visual studio as with debug, I'm getting call stack and locals and that's what matters to me

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at some these presentations from NDC2010:

Advanced Debugging with Visual Studio
http://streaming.ndc2010.no/tcs/?id=B25D60E8-48C1-4514-9276-608859B4CC72

Hardcore .NET Production Debugging
http://streaming.ndc2010.no/tcs/?id=7CA2DE20-2C1E-4E15-B962-5A61426B2218

Both by Ingo Rammer.

Comment: Hi, I watched both of these videos, they are excellent! I think learning WinDbg or Mdbg is the way to go for me, vote up